# NSDate formatter conversion not yielding correct date

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am facing issue with proper date retrieval using date formatter.I have saved the date in the following format:

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

Now I need to display the saved date in view controller.For the convenience of readability and simplicity,I have retrieved the saved date from database and changed to a short format say January 17,February 18 etc..Here is the implementation code for that:

```
remind.Date = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 3)];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:remind.Date];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
NSString *dateVal = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
remind.Date = dateVal;
```

Now the date value will be visible as shown in the following snap shot:

[image]

All these dates are saved in to an array called grpArray

Now I want to retrieve the complete date of formatted date,when I select the row and navigate to controller where that date is saved,for that in did select row at index path I implemented the following code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        ReminderClass *rem = [self.grpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        // Instantiate your detail/editor view controller,
        // and pass in the ReminderClass object to be edited.
        ERAddReminderViewController *rdvc = [[[ERAddReminderViewController alloc]initWithReminder:rem]autorelease];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
        [dateFormat setLenient:YES];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:rem.Date];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        NSString *dateVal = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
        rem.Date = dateVal;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rdvc animated:YES];
        rdvc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Edit";
}
```

Now according to the logic I should get the complete date i.e. format specified.Its working fine but got a problem with correct year and time that was originally saved.Please see the following snap shot for clarification:

[image]

Now the date as we can see is 1970-01-17 00:00:00

But the actual date which I saved was 2012-01-17 19:40:40

What went wrong with the implementation

Can any one please guide me right

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is you're trying to convert a date `MMMM dd` to a `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.
Which ofcourse isn't possible since the date in the first format doesn't know the year and time.
That's why it's showing 1970 00:00:00 , the 01-17 are correct (ofcourse)
You always have to 'store' the original date `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and work with that instead of the formatted one.

Comment: Extremely thankful for the answer,but what I mean to do is display the format as Month Day in cells of table view,when the user selects the row,he/she must be able to view the complete date so that modifications can be done to the existing date.If I am not retrieving the complete date,It is getting displayed as nothing when I come back to previous,So please help me on these lines,thanks :)

Comment: Please see the snap shot,1st where the user can view the dates,and upon selection it navigates to the data where that date is present there I have placed a button(right navigation bar button item) edit for making changes and when modification is finished,he clicks done.Then the modified date gets overwritten with existing,view of it is shown in 2nd screen shot

Comment: Can you show me the code where you add the date to the `grpArray` array?

Comment: Oh sure this is the line I used : [self.grpArray addObject:remind]; where remind is the object of model class holds name,event,date etc.. please see the post where I retrieved the date and assigned to remind.Date.

Comment: Join my chatroom, maybe I can clarify: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7121/basvk

Comment: Please have a look at this question when you find some free time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846659/setting-fire-date-for-local-notification-based-on-condition-not-working